# trying to run multiple python files in one line

Tags: python, ubuntu

So I'm trying to run two Python files in one line in a configuration file and it's not working, what's wrong with the way I've done it.

```
on_event_start python /home/Documents/email_alert.py /home/Documents/sms_alert.py
```

Comment: What makes you think this will work?

Comment: What if `email_alert.py` takes a command line argument?

Comment: I managed to run one file and it worked. Anyway I just tried running more test I might have a problem in one of the files thats why

Answer (score 1):

That will invoke `python`, tell it to run `/home/Documents/email_alert.py`, and pass it `"/home/Documents/sms_alert.py"` as its first argument. You will need to invoke `python` multiple times, once with each script. Whether the configuration file is capable of handling it on its own or if you need to invoke a shell in order to have a command chain is something you will need to check the documentation for.